# Android 2.3.3 and google maps api v2 error starting activity

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have such activityclass code:

```
package com.pavel.exchanger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


public class SearchExchangerActivity extends FragmentActivity   {
    static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
    private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_exchanger);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
            Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Kiel")
                .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_exchanger, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and such layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SearchExchangerActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and such manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pavel.exchanger"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.ExchangerListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_exchanger_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.BankExchangersListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bank_exchangers_list" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.NbrbActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_nbrb" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.***"
            android:value="****" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.pavel.exchanger.SearchExchangerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_exchanger" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but when i run my activity  i get:

```
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pavel.exchanger/com.pavel.exchanger.SearchExchangerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at com.pavel.exchanger.SearchExchangerActivity.onCreate(SearchExchangerActivity.java:29)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
04-30 21:39:32.856: E/AndroidRuntime(435):  ... 11 more
```

all lib's and project (google play) are included....

But why i'm getting this error's? How can i see google map on 2.3.3???

Also if i do such code in activity (default):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_exchanger);  
    }
```

in emulator i see that i need to install google play app....

How to run google maps api v2 on android 2.3.3???

Comment: in addition to Raghunandan's answer: I've tried vector based Map v2 on some low-cost android ICS tablets where it did not run, I guess because of some openGL ES driver/chipset incompatibilities. Due to those issues (no emulator support and potential loss of customers) I still run on Map v1.

Comment: @comeGetSome maybe is it easier to gow for a prev. v1 api? maybe there are good tutorials? some links....

Comment: @comeGetSome i need map tu put there some object-links on bulding, where Lat-long i'm getting via json.... Just show map, and object's on them (coordinates via json)

Comment: its indeed very easy but I'm afraid its too late to get back to v1; Google does not allow to obtain API keys for Maps v1 anymore, as of March 2013: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/

Comment: @comeGetSome  this is bad(((((    what can i do then? is it hard to port my code to android 4* look? i'm afraid of thread's (parsing json)...  are there other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Google Play services is not supported on the Android emulator — to develop using the APIs, you need to provide a development device such as an Android phone or tablet.

The above quote from http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html.

I suggest you run your app on your device.

EDIT:

If you are targeting an application earlier than API level 12, you can access the same functionality through the SupportMapFragment class. You will also have to include the 
[Support Library.](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)

Comment: yet i didn't have android device((( maybe other emulators?      SupportMapFragment  -  i do so...

Comment: or maybe is it easier to gow for a prev. v1 api? maybe there are good tutorials? some links....

Comment: @brabertaser1992 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/. Check the Note

Comment: but how to be with key? (v1 is deprecated)

Comment: I din't understand your comment. You want to know how to get they map api key?

Comment: i mean that now (from march) i could'nt get api v1 key, it's closed

Comment: from March 18th, 2013 you will no longer be able to request an API key for this version from the link. pls check the note from my 1st comment